# Visual Studio for Mac throwing MTOUCH MT0008 error "You should provide one root assembly only"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

Recently upgraded from Xamarin Studio to Visual Studio for Mac. Trying to build an existing iOS project I'm receiving the following build error:

> /Projects/ACME Networks/Alpha Xamarin/iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT0008: You should provide one root assembly only, found 3 assemblies: 'Networks/Alpha', 'Xamarin/iOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone9.1-10.3/Entitlements.xcent/', '/Projects/ACME Networks/Alpha Xamarin/iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/MyNetApp.iOS.exe' (MT0008) (App)

It appears to me that something in the IDE is getting confused because the path to the solution includes folders that have spaces in them, "ACME Networks" and "Alpha Xamarin".

I've got no clue how to fix this. Tried cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: I was able to work around this by simply renaming all the folders in the path to my .sln file and removing the spaces. But this still isn't a solution.

Comment: Amazingly enough, this problem has at least one year old...

Answer (score 3):

Usually this problem means that you have spaces in the directory names of your project.

Visual Studio for Windows allow us to create projects with spaces in the directory names, but Xamarin or Visual Studio for Mac doesn't. When you copy a project from Windows to Mac, it should work right away as they say. But it doesn't, and this is one of the problems.

You can change the spaces to a different character like "_" or "-" or just remove the spaces.

Be sure to edit yourproject.sln file lines pointing to your .csproj files to the new path and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, doesn't really feel like a solution though...

Comment: Really? What, you were expecting me to fix visual Studio? I wish I could.